# Unable to embed image with Swiftmailer with Yii2

Tags: yii2, swiftmailer

I am trying to embed an image in my Email using swiftmailer but it is not getting embed in it. I have tried every solution provided in the forums but still not able to make it work. Below is my code. Please note that I am able to HTML contents in my template but just image is not getting embedded in it.

```
$message = Yii::$app->mailer->compose('registration', ['imgN'=>'\Yii::getAlias('@webroot/assets/image.png')]);

return $message->setFrom($from)->setTo($to)->setSubject(self::$subject)->send();
```

I have also tried using :

```
i) 'imgN'=> Yii::getAlias('@web/assets/image.png'),
ii) 'imgN'=>Yii::getAlias('@app/assets/image.png'),
iii)'imgN'=> '@app/web/assets/image.png',
```

Code in the View:

```
 <?php
     use yii\swiftmailer\Message;
     $message = new Message;
    ?>
```

and in HTML body:

```
    <img src="<?= $message->embed($imgN); ?>" alt="No Image"/>
```

Please point any mistake I may have done?
It would be a big help.
Thanks!

Comment: where have you stored the $imgN  ??

Comment: Its in assets folder that is showing in the path.

Comment: are you sending the email on gmail id or any other ?

Comment: I have tried doing both sending email on gmail and other id's too. The result is the same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606838/error-when-embed-image-in-mail-using-yii2

Comment: Thanks jithin..but the solution provided didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$message = Yii::$app->mailer->compose();
$message->setFrom($from);
$message->setTo($to);
$message->setSubject(self::$subject);
$message->setHtmlBody(Yii::$app->mailer->render('registration', [
    'img' => $message->embed(\Yii::getAlias('@app/assets/image.png')),
], Yii::$app->mailer->htmlLayout));

return $message->send();
```

And in view:

```
<img src="<?= $img ?>">
```

Comment: I am getting thie error below:                                                          Getting unknown property: yii\swiftmailer\Message::htmlLayout

Comment: Its giving this error now:                                                                          Unknown Method – yii\base\UnknownMethodException
Calling unknown method: yii\swiftmailer\Message::render()

Comment: Thank you so very much @Bizley.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to display embedded images with the html of an email.  I found that you couldn't do the normal
       Yii::$app->mailer->compose( 'view_file' )
because you need to reference the "cid" of the embedded image within your html.

You therefore need to create the email object first

```
  $email = Yii::$app->mailer->compose($view, ['model' => $model ])
                    ->setFrom($from)
                    ->setTo($emailTo)
                    ->setSubject($subject);
```

Then create each embedded object

```
  $cid = $email->embed($model->filename,[
                    'fileName' => $model->id,".jpg",
                    'contentType' => 'image/jpeg'
                     ]);
  // save the returned cid
  $images[$item->id] = '<img src="'.$cid.'"/>';
```

Then create the html by rendering your view (or however else you do it)

```
  $html = Yii::$app->mailer->render('@common/mail/receipt', ['model' => $this, 'images' => $images ]);
  $email->setHtmlBody($html);
```

then in your view echo out the images

```
  foreach ( $images as $image )
      echo $image;
```

then send the email

```
   $result = $email->send()
```